# Self-reference object in chained method calls

Tags: c#, self, self-reference

How do you reference the chained method's object in that same method's arguments. Let's say you have a number of chained method calls that trim/substring a string like so:

```
str.Substring(varLen1).Substring(varLen2).Substring(1,##self##.Length-2)
```

The problem is that because the length of the string is now unknown and different from the original string's length, how do I substring like in the last call (a substring where the index and length may depend on the string itself).

Thanks!

Comment: Well I misread the question. You were referring to `##SELF##`, not the method chain :)

Comment: Yep, sorry. I was just commenting on your post :-), but then it was gone...

Comment: Not sure what you want `##SELF##` to refer to. And what is the `Subscript` function?

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be Substring. I have updated the question to try an make it more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

Though with an extension method you could capture `##self##` and use a lambda to continue the expression.

```
public static TResult WithSelf<TSource, TResult> (this TSource x, Func<TSource, TResult> f)
{
    return f (x);
}

str.Substring (STDIN_PFX_FN.Length)
    .Trim (new char[] {'"', ' '})
    .WithSelf (x => x.Substring (1, x.Length - 2))
```

I tend to think that ends up more complicated to read and uglier and simply prefer to create a separate function.

```
str = Clean(str);

private string Clean (string str)
{
    str = str.Substring (STDIN_PFX_FN.Length).Trim (new char[] {'"', ' '});
    return str.Substring (1, str.Length - 2);
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! Good point about doing it in a more functional way, but I agree that becomes more complicated than necessary... I guess the best solution is actually to write my own "SubstringWithIndexFromBack" function and then chain that...